# bind html directive from controller object(string)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to render directive from controllers object that contains tabs headers and html elements. 
This is controller and directive:

```
.controller('OptionsTabsCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $mdToast, $sce) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
        title: 'name',
        content: $sce.trustAsHtml('<layer-headers></layer-headers>')
    }, {
        title: 'styles',
        content: $sce.trustAsHtml("<styles></styles>")
    }, {
        title: 'labels',
        content: $sce.trustAsHtml("<labels></labels>")
    }];
})
.directive('OptionsTabs', ['$compile', '$templateCache', function($compile, $templateCache) {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = $templateCache.get('OptionsTabsTempl.html');
        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: 'OptionsTabsCtrl',
        link: linker
    };
}])
```

And There is html template:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="OptionsTabsTempl.html">
    <mg-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-stretch-tab>
            <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" label="{{tab.title}}">
                <div class="tab{{$index%4}}" style="padding: 25px; text-align: center;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>
                </div>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </mg-content>
</script>
```

Why directive render in DOM, but it not warks at all?
How to forced it?
I have added 'ngSanitize', but it not hepls me.